# package Sencha Touch app to apk

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

we have a ST2 app that works on a website.
we want to package it to an apk.
I use 'sencha app build native' command
(tried production/testing etc instead of native)

Build keeps failing getting this mistake -

```
file not found or cannot be read ../resources/sass/stylesheets/fonts/pictos/pictos-web.woff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use build.phonegap.com site to make apk of your application instead of this.

Comment: that worked, but all the stylesheets\images are not there and basically app can't move past login page - therefore its exactly as sencha builder, can't find required files, even though they are there. so what's the reason?

Comment: After build your project with sencha app build command, did you checked build files that all css and images are present there?

Comment: okay so before apk, map your build application to IIS and check on browser itself.

Comment: yeah, it works in the browser no prob on local(visual studio/webstorm) and on a web server we run with jenkins. Problems only arise when packaging to an apk! :(